# java Jbutton icon, move is okay but when I cancel the move, the source button's icon goes blank

Tags: java, swing, move, point, drag-and-drop

how to code: 
if the drop position is same with the source position do nothing.

I'm using JButtons as my squares, and when I moved(dragged) a piece, it does move but my problem is, if I drag the piece on the same position, meaning I changed my mind and decided to move another piece the icon changes to blank icon.

```
    public class Board extends JPanel {
        private static final String imageFolderPath = "src/resources/images/";
        private ArrayList<Piece>list = new ArrayList<Piece>();
        private ImageIcon img;
        private GridBagConstraints gbc; 
        private DragMouseAdapter listener = new DragMouseAdapter();
        JButton space;
        JButton p;
        ImageIcon blankimg = new ImageIcon(imageFolderPath+"/pieces/blank.png");

        public Board(){
            //set the layout of each panel and make the bg transparent
            this.setOpaque(true);
            this.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
            this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();


        //create a 7x9 empty panels
        for(int x = 0; x<7; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y<9; y++){

                space = new JButton(blankimg);
                space.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"){
                @Override
                protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
                        if (action == MOVE){
                            System.out.print("hereup");
                            if(source.getLocation() == space.getLocation()){
                                return;
                            } else {
                                ((JButton) source).setIcon(blankimg);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
                        return COPY | MOVE;
                    }       
                });
                space.addMouseListener(listener);
                gbc.gridx = x;
                gbc.gridy = y;
                gbc.ipadx = 21;
                gbc.ipady = 2;
                this.add(space,gbc,0);                
            }
        }


    ///create pieces and put them on the board
            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            img = new ImageIcon(imageFolderPath+"/pieces/"+list.get(i).getImg());
            p = new JButton(img);
            p.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"){
                @Override
                protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
                    if (action == MOVE){
                            if(source.getLocation() == p.getLocation()){
                                return;
                            } else {
                                ((JButton) source).setIcon(blankimg);
                            }
                        }
                }

                @Override
                public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
                    return COPY | MOVE;
                }       
            });
            p.addMouseListener(listener);
            gbc.gridx = list.get(i).getX();
            gbc.gridy = list.get(i).getY();
            gbc.ipadx = 21;
            gbc.ipady = 2;    
            this.add(p,gbc,0);
        }        
    }   
    class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
            TransferHandler handler = c.getTransferHandler();
            handler.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.MOVE);          
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(source.getLocation() == space.getLocation())
```

Guess should use `equals()` instead of `==`